# Django forms field not appearing on webpage

Tags: django, forms

Fields I have added in django forms are not visible on webpage.
Attached model, view and html for the reference below.
This is an additional filed which I intent to add to the forms, I am new to Django and learning by enhancing the current project.
***"estimated_headcount"*** is the new filed I have added in the forms.
Thanks

**Model**

```
class EstimatedHeadcount(models.Model):
    count = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = []

    @staticmethod
    def __gotoadmin__():
        return True
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClientProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
        model = ClientProfile
        fields = ('full_name', 'short_name', 'account_payable',
                  'require_job_number', 'currency', 'segment', 'market', 'estimated_headcount', 'is_technicolor',
                  'address')
```

**views.py**

```
def client_profile(request):
        all_profiles = ClientProfile.objects.filter(status='active')
        profile = None
        pid = request.GET.get('pid')
        client_profile_form = ClientProfileForm()

        if pid:
            profile = ClientProfile.objects.get(id=pid)
            client_profile_form = ClientProfileForm(instance=profile)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            client_profile_form = ClientProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
            if client_profile_form.is_valid():
                profile = client_profile_form.save()
                profile.csv_mapping = profile.full_name
                profile.save()

        if profile:
            for task_type in TaskType.objects.all():
                if not profile.task_costs.filter(task_type=task_type):
                    task_cost = TaskCost(task_type=task_type)
                    task_cost.save()
                    profile.task_costs.add(task_cost)

        return render(request, "prod/client_profile.html", {'all_profiles': all_profiles,
                                                            'profile': profile,
                                                            'client_profile_form': client_profile_form})
```

**clientprofile.html**

```
<div class="content">
            <form id='add_new_client_form' method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                    {{ client_profile_form.as_table }}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="lock" type="button"
                                    onclick="unlock(this, '#add_new_client_form')">Unlock
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what your problem is? Which fields aren't appearing that you expect to appear? Also please fix the indentation on the code you have posted above.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, "estimated_headcount" is the new filed I have added in the forms.

Comment: Is `estimated_headcount` a field on the model?

Comment: Yes, question updated with Model code.

Comment: Don't define your own methods with double-underscore names. Your method should just be called `gotoadmin()`. (Although I'm not sure why it's a method at all, given that it just returns a boolean; why not a simple attribute?)

Comment: Thank All, this worked. Couple of issue in the code. Fixed and worked!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code, there is no relation between the `ClientProfile` model and the `EstimatedHeadcount` model.

`estimated_headcount` should be a field on the `ClientProfile` model.

```
class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    estimated_headcount = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Side note: I would expect the estimated headcount to be a numeric value, so an IntegerField or PositiveIntegerField might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers...There is a new error now